# Chunk no Laravel 4.2 utilizando muita memória

Tags: php, laravel, query, memória, relatório

Estou utilizando em uma aplicação uma query para obter dados de uma tabela e em seguida gerar um arquivo `xlsx`. O problema é que retorna muita informação, cerca de **1,5 GB**. Como solução, então estou utilizando o método `chunk()` da **Query Builder** do Laravel 4.2, mas ainda assim estava utilizando muita memória na aplicação. Tentei então remover as variáveis da memória para cada consulta na base utilizando `unset()`, mesmo assim continua utilizando muita memória.

Segue o método que obtêm as informações da base:

```
<?php
    $urlTeste = '';
    $indiceRelatorios = 0;
    class RelatorioJob {

        public function relatorioPadrao ($job, $data)
        {

$padrao = \VW_RelatorioPadrao::whereBetween('DTALTERACAO',array($dataInicial, $dataFinal))
                ->chunk(1000, function($resultados){
                    global $indiceRelatorios;

                    $padraoFormatado = \RelatorioPadraoConverter::modelsToReport($resultados);

                    //array de padroes diferentes de cancelado e diferente de desativado
                    $naoCancelados = [];
                    // criar um array de padroes cancelados (unicos)
                    $cancelados = [];

                    if(!empty($padraoFormatado)){
                        foreach($padraoFormatado as $v){
                            if($v->status == StatusAprovacao::cancelado){
                                $isExist = false;
                                foreach ($cancelados as $c){
                                    if($c->identificador == $v->identificador){
                                        $isExist = true; break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(!$isExist){
                                    $cancelados[] = $v;
                                }
                            } else if($v->status != StatusAprovacao::desativado) {
                                $naoCancelados[] = $v;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                     /* INICIO: Cria diretório e pasta com arquivo */
                    $nomeArqTeste = 'padraoTeste' . $indiceRelatorios . '.xlsx';

                    if(! \File::isDirectory($GLOBALS['urlTeste'])){
                        $teste = \File::makeDirectory($GLOBALS['urlTeste'], 0775, true);
                    }
                    // Teste salvar arquivo
                    $arqTeste = \File::put($GLOBALS['urlTeste'] . $nomeArqTeste, 'Apenas um teste');
                    if ($arqTeste === false){
                        \Log::info('Erro ao salvar arquivo!');
                    }
                    /* FIM: Cria diretório e pasta com arquivo */

                    // Para gravar na pasta
                    $padraoTemplate = new RelatorioPadraoTemplate2();

                    $padraoTemplate->adicionarItemVisualizado($naoCancelados);

                    $padraoTemplate->adicionarItemAplicabilidadePadrao($naoCancelados);

                    $padraoTemplate->adicionarItemPadraoCancelado($cancelados);

                    $this->setHeaderFileName($padraoTemplate->getGeneratedFinalFilename($nomeArqTeste));

                    $padraoTemplate->saveSpreadSheet($GLOBALS['urlTeste'] . $nomeArqTeste);

                    // Avaliar uso de memória
                    \Log::info('Fim da solicitação de Relatório Padrão');
                    \Log::info('Uso de memória: '. (memory_get_usage(true)/1024/1024) . ' MB');

                    $indiceRelatorios++ ;

                    unset($padraoFormatado);
                    unset($naoCancelados);
                    unset($cancelados);
                    unset($padraoTemplate);

                });
```

O uso de memória para 18000 linhas ficou:

```
[2016-12-09 12:02:11] production.INFO: Inicio da JOB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:02:11] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 6 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:02:35] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 74.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:03:02] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 115.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:03:30] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 148.75 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:03:59] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 199.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:04:27] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 232.25 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:04:52] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 266 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:05:21] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 298 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:05:50] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 363.25 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:06:18] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 397.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:06:47] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 430 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:07:16] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 463.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:07:44] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 496.75 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:08:17] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 530.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:08:49] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 563.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:09:20] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 697.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:09:54] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 696.5 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:10:27] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 727 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:11:01] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 761 MB [] []
[2016-12-09 12:11:36] production.INFO: Uso de memória: 785.75 MB [] []
```

Estou ficando sem alternativas quanto a o que posso estar fazendo para solucionar o problema. Agradeço desde já a todos pela atenção.

Comment: O problema é o tamanho do arquivo ou o uso da memória?

Comment: @geekcom é o uso da memória, se eu rodar uma aplicação dessa em um servidor com limitação de memória minha aplicação ira quebrar

Answer (score 0):

Em todo caso se você precisar deixar o arquivo gerado menor use a classe ZipArchive que é uma classe nativa do próprio PHP da seguinte forma:

```
$diretorio = getcwd() . '/pasta_teste/';
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open('nome_arquivo_zip.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) == TRUE){    
      $zip->addFile($diretorio . 'arquivo1.txt', 'arquivo1.txt');
      $zip->addFile($diretorio . 'arquivo2.txt', 'arquivo2.txt');
      echo 'Arquivo criado com sucesso.';
}else{
   exit('O Arquivo não pode ser criado.');
}
$zip->close();
```